# Differentiation and 3 dimensional

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Assume that a Mountain is shaped like a function $z=f(x,y)=sin(xy)$. A Hiker begins at the Point $(0,0,0)$ and wants to reach the Point (1,1,sin(1)), but he is not allowed to get over the Slope of $45°$. Can he do it?

A friend of mine asked that it seems very easy question but yet complicated :).

At first i thought it is Just Question to find Angle Between two Vectors with formula $$cos(\alpha)=\frac{v*w}{|v|*|w|}$$ but it doesn't bring anything

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: You mean *angle* of $45^\circ$ or *slope* of $1$?

Comment: i mean angle of 45°

Answer (score 1):

So you cannot take the path on the surface corresponding to $y=x$ from $x=0$ to $x=1$, because the slope will exceed $1$ near the end of your path. But try a different path:  Follow the $x$-axis from $x=0$ to $x=1$; then follow the surface keeping $x=1$ and letting $y$ go from $0$ to $1$.